# Dataset level access control in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

So I have a number of datasets under the same GCP BQ project, and I want to allow an external user to have read-only and read/write access on a few of them, but other datasets should not be visible to him. What's the best approach for this?

P.S. Probably not going to create an email account for him under our domain, so I'm thinking service accounts.

Comment: [Controlling access to a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out one way to do it:

1. Create service account for external user (with `BigQuery Job User` role so it can be used to run queries in this project)
2. In GCP console web UI, for each dataset to share, click `"SHARE DATASET"`, and in the pop-up panel add the service account created in step 1, with appropriate roles (`BigQuery Data Viewer` or `BigQuery Data Editor`)

Not sure if there's a cleaner way.